# Beacon detection using Estimote SDK crashes in Android Lollipop

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android, estimote

I'm using Estimote sdk for beacon detection in my android application.Everything is working fine till android version 4.4.4.But its getting crashed in Lollipop.I checked this with Estimote github repository.They says like they fixed it in updated sdk.But still crashes for me.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Crash log

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This cannot be run on UI thread, starting BLE scan can be expensive
at com.simelabs.kmb.spotbeak.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:39)
at com.simelabs.kmb.spotbeak.service.BeaconService.checkNotOnUiThread(BeaconService.java:507)
at com.simelabs.kmb.spotbeak.service.BeaconService.access$3(BeaconService.java:505)
at com.simelabs.kmb.spotbeak.service.BeaconService$InternalLeScanCallback.onLeScan(BeaconService.java:485)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter$2.onScanResult(BluetoothAdapter.java:1720)
at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper$1.run(BluetoothLeScanner.java:330)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been solved installing latest estitmote sdk jar i.e., 0.4.3 from the official site:

https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/tree/master/EstimoteSDK

Enjoy!